# Spring ControllerAdvice and authentication/authorization exception handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot appliation I have a following web security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority(Authority.Type.ROLE_ADMIN.getName())
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).ignoringAntMatchers("/login/**")
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
        // @formatter:on
    }

....

}
```

and `ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler  {

    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, ErrorResponse> handleException(Exception exception) {
        return createResponseError(exception);
    }

    private Map<String, ErrorResponse> createResponseError(Exception exception) {
        final Map<String, ErrorResponse> responseError = new HashMap<String, ErrorResponse>();
        responseError.put(ERROR, new ErrorResponse(exception.getMessage()));
        return responseError;
    }

}
```

Right now, when I'm trying to access my secure API urls by anonymous user, I'm receiving a following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri May 06 22:59:05 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
```

Instead of this page, I need to handle such kind of errors in my `ControllerAdvice` (in order to return JSON error response) which is working fine for all other exceptions but only for authenticated users.

How to handle this Authentication/Authorization error by my `GlobalControllerExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ControllerAdvice`s are designed to assist `Controller` classes and `ExceptionHandler`s are for handling exceptions thrown by `Controller`s. `AuthenticationException` and `AccessDeniedException`s are usually thrown by `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` of Spring Security. So, i'm guessing that you won't be able to catch those `AuthenticationException`s using `ControllerAdvice`s, since [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#exceptiontranslationfilter) would already catch them and convert them to appropriate HTTP responses.

The better approach is to use `exceptionHandling` in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Using that, you can configure a `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedHandler`. Here, i'm returning a `403 Forbidden` for access denied cases and a `401 Unauthorized` for missing authentication tokens case:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        http.exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            })
            .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            });
    }

}
```

Using `exceptionHandling` you can configure `ExceptionTranslationFilter` to use `accessDeniedHandler` for handling `AccessDeniedException`s and `authenticationEntryPoint` for `AuthenticationException`s. Take a peek at [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java) to gain more insight about the process.

If you don't like:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri May 06 22:59:05 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
```

And want to customize it, you should provide an implementation for `ErrorController` and return a `Map<String, ErrorResponse>` for errors.